# preserve information is stored in SharePoint site

Tags: site

I'm having SharePoint 2007 site.
I need to close this site 
And therefore I want to preserve all the information is stored just now in the site.

Important detail:
I don't have authorizations to inherit her.

someone has an idea how to solve the problem??

thanks
Liron :)

Comment: Can you give us some more details:
What do you mean with "close this site"? 
-Take it offline?
-Make it read-only?

What permissions do you have and what do you want to inherit?

Comment: Please clarify, this is a bit ambiguous and can lead to a lot of varying answers which may not be right.

Comment: Hi alex! thank you for react my quetion. I need to take the site offline (terminate it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am really not sure if I understand you correctly, but if you need a copy of your site you can do it by backing it up. You can use the central admin, stsadm or powershell for that purpose.

EDIT (1): **Backup & Restore your Site**

Use: stsadm -o backup -url  -filename  [-overwrite]
Example: stsadm -o backup -url http://myserver/myweb -filename C:\temp\backup.bak

Then use: stsadm -o restore -url  -filename  [-overwrite]
Example: stsadm -o restore -url http://myserver/archivweb -filename C:\temp\backup.bak

EDIT (2): **Copy your list to another site**

Go to the list you need to copy -> Settings -> List settings -> Save list as template -> Enter file name, template name and check "Include content" checkbox -> OK

Go to the List Template Gallery -> Download the template you just created -> Upload it to the List Template Gallery of your target site collection -> Go to the site where you want to have your list -> Click Site actions -> Create -> Choose your list from the Custom lists area.

Comment: or if you want to close it, you can remove rights of users

Comment: actually yes, I need to copy my site. can you please guide me step after step how can I copy my site content to anothe new site? and it is be very useful for me if you could explain me how to copy one sharepoint list to another sharepoint list without define all the column type in the second time. thank! thank! thank!

Comment: Again, you are asking 2 different things, above you say you want to close/terminate the site and here you are saying you want to copy data from one site to another.

Comment: I sorry if am not informative myself properly. I want to close the site. But before I will close the site I want to copy the contents that there is in him. And especially to copy the lists that he contains.

Comment: @Liron: I would suggest that you split your question next time, if they contain more than one steps or actions. However, I edited my answer and now it answers both things.